# Inserting to content://sms/sent creates new conversation

Tags: android, sms

When my app sends an sms, I use `.insert` into `content://sms/sent`. That works, but for some reason, in the conversation list, (default Desire messaging app) a new conversation appears in addition to the already existing one with same phone number. It happens no matter which contact I choose. When inserting, I only use the phone number and message text. I guess I need to specify person somehow. The question is how? I get the contact using contact picker.

Comment: Since that content provider is not documented, not supported, not supposed to be used, and not necessarily available on all devices, the fact that it is not working the way you expect should not come as a surprise.

Comment: Then what way should I go to insert sms into sent? I appreaciate your help.

Comment: Maintain your own database of messages sent from your own app.

Comment: But how do I make messages appear in system's database? Like eg Handcent does.

Comment: Handcent is using the undocumented, unsupported, not-supposed-to-be used technique that you are trying and having trouble with.

Comment: Thanks for your patience, one more question - so is there any correct way to add entries to /data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/db/mmssms.db?

Comment: No. That database and application may not exist on any given device, may not be used on any given device, or it may exist in a different form (e.g., different columns, different foreign key relationships) on some devices. So far, SMS client developers have been lucky that this stuff has remained stable, but that is far from a guarantee.